# How to pass a value from a @ApplicationScoped to a @ViewScoped?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

When trying to pass the value I receive this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to >create managed bean createController.  The following problems were found:
>
> Property configMB for managed bean createController does not exist.  Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.
>
> The scope of the object referenced by expression #{configMB}, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (createController) scope of view at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:138)

Is it possible to pass a value from @ApplicationScoped to @ViewScoped?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject long-life beans into short-life beans. (Not vice versa)

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppBean {

    private Object someValue;

    //getters
} 

@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean {

    @Inject
    private AppBean appBean;

    public void sendForm() {
       Object value = appBean.getSomeValue();
       // do things...
    }
}
```

Comment: "_You can inject long-life beans into short-life beans. (Not vice versa)_" wrong... you can with cdi managed beans sice proxies are used